# WHat are the difference between "I cooked dinner in 1 hour" & "I cooked dinner for 1 hour"?

Tags: prepositions

WHat are the difference between "I cooked dinner in 1 hour" & "I cooked dinner for 1 hour"?

[The dictionary says](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/at-on-and-in-time):

We use **in** to say how long it takes someone to do something:

*He was such a clever musician. He could learn a song in about five minutes.*

[The dictionary also says](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/for)

We use **for** with a period of time to refer to duration (how long something lasts):

*There’s a lovely open-air pool near us. We usually go there for a couple of hours in the evenings when it’s warm enough.*

SO, "I cooked dinner in 1 hour" =  it took me 1 hour to cook dinner

& "I cooked dinner for 1 hour" =  cooking dinner  lasted 1 hour

When to use "*I cooked dinner in 1 hour*" & when to use "*I cooked dinner for 1 hour*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cooked the dinner in two hours.

Implies the dinner was ready after 2 hours.

> I cooked the dinner for two hours.

Implies for 2 hours I was busy cooking the dinner.

 **for** shows a length of time whereas **in** expresses that something was complete after a certain time.